# "Every elementary function is differentiable."

Tags: derivatives, elementary-functions

Edwards and Larson (Calculus, [2018](https://books.google.com/books?id=gt65DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA378&dq=%22you%20can%20differentiate%20any%20elementary%20function%22)) claim that:

> You can differentiate *any* elementary function.

It [seems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2975798/) though that this claim is false.

How then can we modify the above claim so that it becomes true?

Perhaps for example it is true that every elementary function is differentiable except on a set of isolated points?

(ProofWiki definitions of [elementary function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Elementary_Function) and [differentiability](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Differentiable_Mapping/Real-Valued_Function).)

Comment: The function $x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert$ does not seem to be elementary  according to Wikipedia. I would not say the claim is false using that example.

Comment: @Gibbs: Could you add to that other question an answer arguing that the absolute value function isn't elementary?

Comment: I am not saying it is not, I am saying it does not seem to be. Perhaps I should ask how you proved that it is elementary.

Comment: @Gibbs: We have $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, so that the absolute value function is the composition of two elementary functions. Hence, by [definition](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Elementary_Function), it is also elementary.

Comment: You are right. What I am thinking now is that probably the authors did not have in mind a formal definition---do they use a specific definition of elementary function in that book?

Comment: This is a sterile discussion IMHO. What is the difference between a "elementary function" and any other function? There is none; just a psychological effect.

Comment: @dtcm840 Consider the function $x \mapsto \sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{x-1}$. It is elementary in the sense Wikipedia explains, but it is not differentiable because it consists only of a point.

Comment: Please do not put in quotes something that is not a direct quote, namely the claim "Every elementary function is differentiable" in your question title.

Comment: @Rahul: Those are scare quotes, suggesting that the sentence may not be true, rather than quoting anyone.

Comment: @Gibbs: Yes I believe your example is to my point. Which is about how we can modify the false (?) statement "every elementary function is differentiable" so that it is true.

Comment: @dtcm840 my example should tell that there exist elementary functions which are not differentiable. So it is not true that every elementary function is differentiable except on a set of isolated points. What I mean is that the concept of "elementary function" looks vague to give a general statement.

Answer (score 4):

If you interpret "you can differentiate any elementary function" as "every elementary function is differentiable on $\mathbb R$", then the statement is false.

However, the book actually says something else:

> With the differentiation rules introduced so far in the text, you can differentiate any elementary function. For convenience, these differentiation rules are summarized below. [derivatives table is given]

which is very likely to be true (I didn't read the book, so it's an assumption), as in:

> No techniques beyond those already introduced are necessary to arrive at the list of differentiation rules, applicable to all elementary functions where they are differentiable, that we are about to list below.

The important thing when reading mathematics is to be aware that some statements will be vague and not really correct when taken too literally. However, they are not required to be, unless they are specifically tagged to be definitions or theorems. Just read with grain of salt and you'll be fine.

Comment: I appreciate this, but my question was less about whether Edwards and Larson are right/wrong but more about, "how we can modify the above claim so that it becomes true?"

Comment: @dtcm840: the elementary functions are *formally* differentiable. I am afraid you are splitting hairs.

Comment: @dtcm840, did I not restate the sentence in a way I believe is what the authors intended to say? I might have misunderstood what you ask. If you ask what I now think you are asking, you can't get an answer unless you specifically write down what definition of elementary functions do you want to use.

Comment: Please see ProofWiki definition of [elementary function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Elementary_Function).

Comment: @dtcm840, upon reflection and considering comments by Gibbs, it seems unlikely that a meaningful general statement for all elementary functions can be made. If you derive basic identities, like the table presented in the book you gave a link to, and if you are aware of general rules for differentiation (composition, sum, product and quotient) and the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem), you can decide for any elementary function where it is differentiable and what the derivative is.

Answer (score 1):

An elementary function is in the first place a *function term* composed using certain rules: you may use a single variable $x$, complex constants, $+$, $-$, $*$, $:$, $\exp$, $\log$, $\circ$, etc., but not "cases", as in the definition of ${\rm abs}:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$. When such a function term defines an actual real or complex function on a reasonable subset of ${\mathbb R}$ this function is called *elementary* as well. Note that the function $x\mapsto {1\over x}$ is a bona fide elementary function even though it is undefined at $x=0$.

When it is said that "all elementary functions are differentiable" the meaning is that the derivative of a legal elementary function term, computed according to the rules, is again a legal elementary function term.